# is it possible to call observer for only once after completing all the queries (insert/update/delete)?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm new to room & livedata. My task is to get the data through service and insert into room database and update the UI through livedata observer but whenever I'm doing this task, observer is calling for 3 times because of livedata changes(insert, update or delete). But actually what I need is to call observer only once after completing all the queries (insert/update/delete), then remove the observers from main thread. Please anyone help to resolve

Observer initialization from main fragment :

```
int updateCount=0; // i don't like to use this count
    public void configureViewModel(){
        SCREEN_ID=SCREEN_NO_ADDRESS_DETAIL;
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(DynamicUIViewModel.class);
        viewModel.init(SCREEN_ID,loanType);
        Observer observer=new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Object o) {
                List<DynamicUITable> list=(List<DynamicUITable>)o;
                updateCount++;
                if(updateCount==3) {
                    viewModel.getDynamicUITableLiveData().removeObserver(this); // i want to remove observer without checking this updateCount condition.
                    updateCount=0;
                    updateUI(list);
                }
            }
        };
        viewModel.getDynamicUITableLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), observer);
    }

Repository Class :
 public LiveData<List<DynamicUITable>> init(String screenName,String loanType){
                try {
                    refreshData(screenName,loanType);
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return  dynamicUIDao.load(screenName);
    }



Service call method :
  private void refreshData(final String screenName,String loanType){
        try{
            executor.execute(()->{
                boolean dataExist = (dynamicUIDao.getTableBasedOnScreen(screenName) != null);

                dynamicUIWebservice.getDynamicUIFromServer(screenName).enqueue(new Callback<List<DynamicUITable>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<DynamicUITable>> call, Response<List<DynamicUITable>> response) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "DATA REFRESHED FROM NETWORK");
                        executor.execute(()-> {
                            List<DynamicUITable> dynamicUITableList = response.body();
                            if (dynamicUITableList != null) {
                                if (dataExist) {
                                    dynamicUIDao.deleteRecords(screenName);
                                    dynamicUIDao.save(dynamicUITableList);
                                } else {
                                    dynamicUIDao.save(dynamicUITableList);
                                    dynamicUIDao.load(screenName);
                                }
                               /* From here observer is calling whenever live data changes but what i need is , i need to 
                                call observer only one time after completion all query operation*/
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<DynamicUITable>> call, Throwable t) {
                    }
                });
            });
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/adibfara/Lives and specifically `zip`

Answer (score 0):

You could run all the db operations in one [Transaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction.html).
This will cause your observers to be notified once since the insert, replace and delete will be done in a single transaction.

Comment: in that case first it is triggering observer from select query before calling service..see my below code.

Comment: public LiveData<List<DynamicUITable>> init(String screenName,String loanType){
                try {
                    refreshData(screenName,loanType); // from here i'am calling service then data will insert / update.
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return  dynamicUIDao.load(screenName); // from here it is triggering observer first
    }